A formula to select the highest cell in a row that then shows the entire row
I would like to do the following:
Find the highest cell in a column in an excel spreadsheet.
Display that entire row.
I have a spreadsheet that tracks our Walks that shows:
Number of Walks (Column A)
Date (Column B)
Location (Column C)
Distance in Miles (Column D)
Total Elevation in Feet (Column E)
Total Time HH:MM (Column F)
Moving Time HH:MM (Column G)
Stopped Time HH:MM (Column H)
Average Speed MPH (Column I)
Average Moving Speed MPH (Column J)

I would like to use formulas to display the entire row of the longest walk, the highest elevation and fastest walk etc. On a different Sheet


Select every cell, and enter the following formula as a basis for the conditional formatting:
=$B1=MAX($B$1:$B$40)

Whenever the value of your row in column "B" is the largest of all cells from "B1" up to "B40", then every cell in your row will be coloured.
